What's the unitary transformation to rotate the state of a generic qubit $|\psi\rangle$ to $|1\rangle$?
Suppose that I have a qubit whose quantum state is a generic state
$$|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$$
I would like to rotate the state of this qubit to the state $|1\rangle$.
How can I achieve that by using unitary transformations? Is there a way to achieve that by using rotation gates ($R_X$, $R_Y$, $R_Z$)?
Thank you in advence!

Could you please clarify whether $|\psi\rangle$ is an arbitrary but fixed state, or if it is entirely arbitrary?

Yes, the state is a fixed arbitrary state

Let $|\psi^{\perp}\rangle = \overline{\beta}|0\rangle - \overline{\alpha}|1\rangle$. This defines a state that is orthogonal to $|\psi\rangle$, i.e. $\langle \psi^{\perp}|\psi\rangle = 0$. Thus $\{|\psi\rangle, |\psi^{\perp}\rangle\}$ form an orthonormal basis.
Then a unitary that performs the action that you want can be written as
$$
U = |0 \rangle \langle \psi^{\perp}| + |1\rangle\langle \psi|\,.
$$
You can check that indeed $U$ is unitary, i.e., $UU^\dagger = U^{\dagger}U = I$ and $U |\psi\rangle = |1\rangle$.
To answer your second question, yes you can implement any qubit unitary using $\{R_X, R_Y, R_Z\}$. I'll let you work that part out.

It is unclear to me that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are fixed. I read the question as asking for a way to reset an arbitrary qubit to the $|1\rangle$ state, which cannot be done unitarily.

Yes, the OP should clarify this then, I clearly interpreted the question differently.

Yes, the state is fixed and I would like to construct a rotation gate U based on the state of the qubit.

A different way of thinking about the same problem... up to a global phase, you can write your state as
$$
|\psi\rangle=\cos\theta|0\rangle+\sin\theta e^{i\phi}|1\rangle.
$$
Start by applying the phase gate $U_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\phi} \end{bmatrix}$. Depending on your definitions, you might call this something like $R_z(2\phi)$. So, now you have
$$
U_1|\psi\rangle=\cos\theta|0\rangle+\sin\theta |1\rangle=R_Y(-2\theta)|0\rangle=R_Y(\pi+2\theta)|1\rangle.
$$
So, now just apply $U_2=R_Y(-\pi-2\theta)$.
